# SSL in HttpContext.Current.Response

Tags: asp.net, ssl, httpresponse

Might be a dumb question but I need a confirmation regardless.  In ASP.NET, if a file was downloaded on a page that was protected by SSL, through a server-side postback that writes to HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, is the transmission that file ALSO protected by SSL?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the download was initiated by a postback or a relative URL, yes.